# php help constructing part numbers

Tags: php

I need to create a large list of part numbers from instructions for how they can be constructed.
Here are two examples.

- APXE-N-300-025-A0-12-ET-OO
- APXE-N-300-050-A0-12-ET-OO

Each part number is broken into segments like: 0-1-2-3-4-5-6 and some parts have dependencies where, depending on the value of prior parts, there is a restricted selection for that particular part.

Here's the php I have so far. I have an array that sort of contains the pattern but I'm struggling to create the loop that outputs all the options:

```
$parts[0] = array('APXE');
$parts[1] = array('N','P',"S");
$parts[2] = array('300','400','600','700','800','900','1G4','1G8','2G0','2G5');
$parts[3] = array(
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'300','values'=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'400','values'=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'600','values'=>array('1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'700','values'=>array('200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'800','values'=>array('075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'900','values'=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G4','values'=>array('075','150','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G8','values'=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G0','values'=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G5','values'=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'))
);
$parts[4] = array(
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'300','values'=>array('A0','A1','A2')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'400','values'=>array('B0','B1','B2','C0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'600','values'=>array('D0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'700','values'=>array('E0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'800','values'=>array('F0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'900','values'=>array('G0','G2','G3','G4')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G4','values'=>array('H0','H1')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G8','values'=>array('K0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G0','values'=>array('I0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G5','values'=>array('J0','J1'))
);
$parts[5] = array('12','1L','24','48','AC');
$parts[6] = array('ET','FC','IC','FI','NT');
$parts[7] = array('OO');

foreach($parts as $part)
foreach ($part as $bit){
 if(!is_array($bit) $list[] = $bit;
 else foreach($bit['values'] as $val) $list[] = $val;
} //??
```

In the above 'dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'300' means that for all part numbers with '300' in the 2nd segment, the 3rd segment can have all that array's values.

**I'm looking for a PHP function that is flexible enough to handle it when there are varying number of segments. Also the dependencies will change. So in the above example 4 could depend on 3 and 6 could depend on 1.**

Can anyone say recursion? lol

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your plea for help on Facebook pointing to this post and decided to take a whack at this.

I changed the way your dependencies are listed, but I believe this to work (despite it being a bit rushed and brute force-like). Hopefully it will give you a good place to start.

```
/*
* The following arrays should be formatted thusly: 
* $exclusionlist[indexOfDeterminingColumn][indexOfDependentColumn] = array(
*   'ValueOfDeterminingColumn' => array('list', 'of', 'valid', 'values')
* );
*/

$dependencyList[3][2] = array(
    '300' => array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'),
    '400' => array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'),
    '600' => array('1M7','3M5'),
    '700' => array('200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'),
    '800' => array('075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'),
    '900' => array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'),
    '1G4' => array('075','150','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0'),
    '1G8' => array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'),
    '2G0' => array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'),
    '2G5' => array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M')
);
$dependencyList[4][2] = array(
    '300' => array('A0','A1','A2'),
    '400' => array('B0','B1','B2','C0'),
    '600' => array('D0'),
    '700' => array('E0'),
    '800' => array('F0'),
    '900' => array('G0','G2','G3','G4'),
    '1G4' => array('H0','H1'),
    '1G8' => array('K0'),
    '2G0' => array('I0'),
    '2G5' => array('J0','J1')
);

$dependencyList[5][1] = array(
    'N' => array('12'),
    'P' => array('1L'),
    'S' => array('24')
);

// $segments contains lists of all valid values for each segment of the part number
$segments[0] = array('APXE');
$segments[1] = array('N','P',"S");
$segments[2] = array('300','400','600','700','800','900','1G4','1G8','2G0','2G5');
$segments[3] = array('025','050','075','14M','150','1M0','1M7','200','250','3M5','500','7M0');
$segments[4] = array('A0','A1','A2','B0','B1','B2','C0','D0','E0','F0','G0','G2','G3','G4','H0','H1','I0','J0','J1','K0');
$segments[5] = array('12','1L','24','48','AC');
$segments[6] = array('ET','FC','IC','FI','NT');
$segments[7] = array('OO');

$partNumbers = array();

// Loop through each segment's array
foreach($segments[0] as $segment0)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[0])}, key($dependencyList[0]), $segment0, 0, $dependencyList))
foreach($segments[1] as $segment1)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[1])}, key($dependencyList[1]), $segment1, 1, $dependencyList))
foreach($segments[2] as $segment2)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[2])}, key($dependencyList[2]), $segment2, 2, $dependencyList))
foreach($segments[3] as $segment3)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[3])}, key($dependencyList[3]), $segment3, 3, $dependencyList))
foreach($segments[4] as $segment4)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[4])}, key($dependencyList[4]), $segment4, 4, $dependencyList))
foreach($segments[5] as $segment5)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[5])}, key($dependencyList[5]), $segment5, 5, $dependencyList))
foreach($segments[6] as $segment6)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[6])}, key($dependencyList[6]), $segment6, 6, $dependencyList))
foreach($segments[7] as $segment7)
if(!testForExclusion(${'segment'.key($dependencyList[7])}, key($dependencyList[7]), $segment7, 7, $dependencyList))
$partNumbers[] = $segment0.'-'.$segment1.'-'.$segment2.'-'.$segment3.'-'.$segment4.'-'.$segment5.'-'.$segment6.'-'.$segment7;


echo count( $partNumbers ); 

echo '<p>';

echo implode('<br/>', $partNumbers);

function testForExclusion($determiningValue, $determiningSegment, $testValue, $testSegment, $exclusionList){
    $excluded = false;

    if(isset($exclusionList[$testSegment][$determiningSegment][$determiningValue])){
        if(!in_array($testValue, $exclusionList[$testSegment][$determiningSegment][$determiningValue])){
            $excluded = true;
        }
    }

    return $excluded;
}
```

EDIT: The data structure and dependency function should be able to be used for any combination of dependencies, so this solution should be expandable.

Comment: Greg - I love this! Love the way you think. I edited what you provided a bit to show how I've made it more dynamic depending on the dependencies that are entered in. I've also taken out the {'s to make it easier for someone who doesn't program to use this (e.g. I'll probably have an assistant actually generate all the variations). It runs fast too. Thanks so much for giving me part of your brain for a few minutes.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help! It was a great way to stretch my mind for a bit!

Answer (score 0):

First I think it would be good to see if you can generate one part number by using `array_rand()` which picks one or more random entries out of an array.  Later you can modify the code to use recursion or nested `foreach` to output all possible parts.

```
foreach ($parts as $part)
{
    if (!is_array($part[0]))
        $list[] = array_rand($part);
    else
    {
        $val = "UNKNOWN";
        // Handle dependencies by looking back to the relevant section of 
        // the current part number that is being generated.
        foreach ($part as $bit)
            if ($list[$bit['dependIndex']] == $bit['dependVal'])
                $val = array_rand($bit['values']);
        $list[] = $val;
    }
}

var_dump($list);
```

Generating all possible parts is a fairly hard problem.  If this is a homework question, your professor must have a lot of confidence in you!

Comment: thanks. I don't think randomness has anything to do with what I want to accomplish. I need to compile a complete list of possible part numbers based on the instructions in the array. I just don't know how to do that with the dependances. I tried your code but it did not produce what I needed: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b96c6a579ecdebec7a1c3945d847481353ecd29

Comment: Answer modified slightly.  I don't think sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com is working properly because `is_array()` is returning true for everything, when it doesn't on my PHP interpreter.

Comment: No I work at an actual company and need this function. I've edited your code as it was missing a semicolon and generating an error in php for me. I've printed $list and it outputs: `array(7) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(2) [5]=> int(2) [6]=> int(0) } ` I'm still not sure what purpose rand would serve. There's no randomness in this requirement but rather part numbers need to be built sequentially in all their possible configurations.

Comment: That’s because of sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com .  Try it on an actual PHP stack and you'll see it select some random strings.

Comment: Yea I ran this exact code on my apache/php server and it output what I gave. Also there's no randomness in the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 functions you are looking to perform. One for resolving the dependencies, and one for the number generation.

Given the dependencies in the following model:

```
$dependencies = array(
    '300'=>array(
        0=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'),
        1=>array('A0','A1','A2')
    ),
    '400'=>array(
        0=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('B0','B1','B2','C0')
    ),
    '600'=>array(
        0=>array('1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('D0')
    ),
    '700'=>array(
        0=>array('200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('E0')
    ),
    '800'=>array(
        0=>array('075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('F0')
    ),
    '900'=>array(
        0=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('G0','G2','G3','G4')
    ),
    '1G4'=>array(
        0=>array('075','150','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0'), 
        1=>array('H0','H1')
    ),
    '1G8'=>array(
        0=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'), 
        1=>array('H0','H1')
    ),
    '2G0'=>array(
        0=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'), 
        1=>array('I0')
    ),
    '2G5'=>array(
        0=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'), 
        1=>array('J0','J1')
    )
);
```

you can create a function that combines positions 3, 4, and 5 into a pre-calculated string:

```
function position3($arrays){
    $retVal = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $key=>$value){
        foreach ($value[0] as $v1){
            foreach ($value[1] as $v2){
                array_push($retVal, $key . '-' . $v1 . '-' . $v2);
            }
        }
    }
    return $retVal;
}
```

With position 3 combined in all of the defined mutations, you can map the positions into an array model as follows:

```
$parts[0] = array('APXE');
$parts[1] = array('N','P',"S");
$parts[2] = position3($dependencies);
$parts[3] = array('12','1L','24','48','AC');
$parts[4] = array('ET','FC','IC','FI','NT');
$parts[5] = array('OO');
```

You can then call a looping function that build each permutation of your combined values (in total, 13275) with this function:

```
function go($parts){
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($parts[0] as $pos1){
        foreach ($parts[1] as $pos2){
            foreach ($parts[2] as $pos3){
                foreach ($parts[3] as $pos4){
                    foreach ($parts[4] as $pos5){
                        foreach ($parts[5] as $pos6 ){
                            echo implode('-', [$pos1,$pos2,$pos3,$pos4,$pos5,$pos6 ])."\n";
                            $total++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo $total;
}
```

Putting this all together will make:

```
function position3($arrays){

    $retVal = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $key=>$value){
        foreach ($value[0] as $v1){
            foreach ($value[1] as $v2){
                #echo $key . '-' . $v1 . '-' . $v2 . "\n";
                array_push($retVal, $key . '-' . $v1 . '-' . $v2);
            }
        }
    }
    return $retVal;
}



$dependencies = array(
    '300'=>array(
        0=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'),
        1=>array('A0','A1','A2')
    ),
    '400'=>array(
        0=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('B0','B1','B2','C0')
    ),
    '600'=>array(
        0=>array('1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('D0')
    ),
    '700'=>array(
        0=>array('200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('E0')
    ),
    '800'=>array(
        0=>array('075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('F0')
    ),
    '900'=>array(
        0=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5'), 
        1=>array('G0','G2','G3','G4')
    ),
    '1G4'=>array(
        0=>array('075','150','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0'), 
        1=>array('H0','H1')
    ),
    '1G8'=>array(
        0=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'), 
        1=>array('H0','H1')
    ),
    '2G0'=>array(
        0=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'), 
        1=>array('I0')
    ),
    '2G5'=>array(
        0=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'), 
        1=>array('J0','J1')
    )
);

$parts[0] = array('APXE');
$parts[1] = array('N','P',"S");
$parts[2] = position3($dependencies);
$parts[3] = array('12','1L','24','48','AC');
$parts[4] = array('ET','FC','IC','FI','NT');
$parts[5] = array('OO');



function go($parts){
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($parts[0] as $pos1){
        foreach ($parts[1] as $pos2){
            foreach ($parts[2] as $pos3){
                foreach ($parts[3] as $pos4){
                    foreach ($parts[4] as $pos5){
                        foreach ($parts[5] as $pos6 ){
                            echo implode('-', [$pos1,$pos2,$pos3,$pos4,$pos5,$pos6 ])."\n";
                            $total++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo $total;
}

go($parts);
```

Comment: wow! this outputs all the part numbers. Thanks for your efforts on this. The reason I supplied the array like I did though was that dependencies will shift. For example we might need to make part[4] dependent on part[3] or part[6] dependent on part[4]. This range of part numbers is for one of a few dozen products and each has different dependencies at different stages of the part number. They are all of course dependent on prior parts in the number. Hmm... how would you handle that? I can supply some other array examples if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want here... this is a very brute-force way of dealing with it, but should work:

```
<?php
$parts[0] = array('APXE');
$parts[1] = array('N','P',"S");
$parts[2] = array('300','400','600','700','800','900','1G4','1G8','2G0','2G5');
$parts[3] = array(
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'300','values'=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'400','values'=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'600','values'=>array('1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'700','values'=>array('200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'800','values'=>array('075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'900','values'=>array('025','050','075','150','200','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G4','values'=>array('075','150','250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G8','values'=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G0','values'=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G5','values'=>array('250','500','1M0','1M7','3M5','7M0','14M'))
);
$parts[4] = array(
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'300','values'=>array('A0','A1','A2')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'400','values'=>array('B0','B1','B2','C0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'600','values'=>array('D0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'700','values'=>array('E0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'800','values'=>array('F0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'900','values'=>array('G0','G2','G3','G4')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G4','values'=>array('H0','H1')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'1G8','values'=>array('K0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G0','values'=>array('I0')),
 array('dependIndex'=>'2','dependVal'=>'2G5','values'=>array('J0','J1'))
);
$parts[5] = array('12','1L','24','48','AC');
$parts[6] = array('ET','FC','IC','FI','NT');
$parts[7] = array('OO');

foreach($parts[1] as $eigth){
    foreach($parts[2] as $sect){
        foreach($parts[3] as $keya => $firstloop){
            foreach($parts[3][$keya] as $itemone){
                foreach($parts[3][$keya]['values'] as $firstselector){
                    foreach($parts[4] as $keyb => $secondloop){
                        foreach($parts[4][$keyb] as $itemtwo){
                            foreach($parts[4][$keyb]['values'] as $secondselector){
                                foreach($parts[5] as $halve){
                                    foreach($parts[6] as $quarter){
                                        if($sect == $parts[3][$keya]['dependVal'] && $sect == $parts[3][$keyb]['dependVal']){
                                            echo $parts[0][0] . "-" . $eigth . "-" . $sect . "-" . $firstselector . "-" . $secondselector . "-" . $halve . "-" . $quarter . "<br>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```